# is this code normal behavior of ORMs?

Tags: java, sqlite, orm, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have these two objects : **Project** and **History**

Here are the minimal codes of those classes

**Project**

```
@Entity(name = "projects")
public class Project {

  @Id
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(MappedBy = "project")
  private List<History> histories;
}
```

**History**

```
@Entity(name = "histories")
public class History {

  @Id
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColum(name = "project_name")
  private Project project;
}
```

I have no troubles creating the EntityManager and creating the tables. Everything is here with the right columns gently waiting for the data to be inserted.

But then, I am not sure if this is the right behavior of ORMs.

Basically it would be ideal if it could look like that :

- create **History** + set **History**
- create **Project** + set **Project** + add **History** in **Project**'s list *histories*
- insert **Project** in the database using its DAO

When I try to execute such a code, only the *projects* table has data in, *histories* table is empty, which force me to write my code as folow :

- create **History** + set **History**
- create **Project** + set **Project** + add **History** in **Project**'s list *histories*
- insert **History** in the database using its DAO
- insert **Project** in the database using its DAO

Ok, this is just one extra line of code but what if I need to fetch the data or add more histories to one **Project** ?
If so, I would need to load the project and all the associated histories and add the physical histories to the **Project** object... such a code would easily get cumbersome and bothersome to write.

Anyways, is this the normal behavior of any ORMs or is my ORM fooling me ?

**note** : I'm using ORMLite with SQLite driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the behavior you're observing is the default behavior, but you should be able to change it and make the underlying `History` objects be persisted by default. On your `@OneToMany` annotation in `Project`, try specifying the `cascade` field as `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` (assuming you're using `javax.persistence.OneToMany`). See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#cascade()) for other options.